# Wireshark CAN : meaning of padding and reserved fields

Tags: wireshark, can-bus

I captured CAN frames with Wireshark, and when I observed the bit sequence, it turned not to follow the standard.
Precisely, in Wireshark, bits sequences labeled as "padding" and "reserved" are added. [image: see screenshot]
Where do they come from ?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably some oversimplification so that they can use the same format regardless of 11 or 29 bits. There's no telling if they account for paddings bits or not. Overall it looks like useless console junk from which no conclusions can be made... Doesn't Wireshark come with a better graphical representation? I've only used it for TCP/IP though, for CAN I use commercial, dedicated listeners.

Comment: That layout fits to the datastructure `can_frame` (or `canfd_frame`) which [SocketCAN](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/can.html) uses internally.  I.e. these fields are added by the kernel and do not really have a meaning nor has this data been received from the bus.